# TypeError: Expected bytes While printing Any Report Using Client Database in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7

I am using Client Database and it will be restored successfully in my local system and working fine but when I am printing any report the within that database at that time.

I got the below traceback from the terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/web/addons/web/http.py", line 285, in dispatch
r = method(self, **self.params)
File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1769, in index
cookies={'fileToken': int(token)})
File "/home/best/workspace/dynaweld/web/addons/web/http.py", line 332, in make_response
response.set_cookie(k, v)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1008, in set_cookie
self.charset))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/http.py", line 920, in dump_cookie
value = to_bytes(value, charset)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/_compat.py", line 106, in to_bytes
raise TypeError('Expected bytes')
TypeError: Expected bytes
```

**I have tried the following way to resolve above traceback issue but I have not yet succeed.**

**1.** Try remove the unwanted data from my local client database remove the all the data of  mail.message object.

**2.** Remove all the unnecessary database from my system and using only 2-3 database for my OpenERP Server Run.

**3.** Clean my pc for unwanted files and other detail which was not relevant for my database.

**4.** I have also check with my enough memory space but I have that enough space  for restoring that database file.

Can any one help me how can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because cookies are not intended to support unicode characters, you must use a decoded variable in the cookie you are trying to set. something like :

```
set_cookie(k, bytes(v))
```

or at least send your variable as bytes.

Comment: this is part of wrekzeug packages of python not part of my module so how we can resolve this kind of issue from our side.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by installing an older version of werkzeug, 0.6.2